# XSLT 2.0 transformation to copy node if a child node exists

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have to transform XML data. The size of input XML is huge, so we need to transform it such that we can get only required data from that. Unnecessary nodes should be omitted. I posted below the sample of structure we get. Input has multiple child nodes, but i need to pick only the child node with data in education node. I am new to XSL transformations. I tried writing some style sheets, but nothing worked as expected.

**Input XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<parent>
    <child>
        <age>30</age>
        <name>
            <firstname>abc</firstname>
            <lastname>xyz</lastname>
            <middlename>v</middlename>
        </name>
        <education>
            <graduate>Yes</graduate>
            <masters>No</masters>
        </education>
        <dob>25-MAR-1990</dob>
        <location>city123</location>        
    </child>
    <child>
        <age>29</age>
        <name>
            <firstname>def</firstname>
            <lastname>123</lastname>
            <middlename>a</middlename>
        </name>
        <education/>
        <dob>25-MAR-1991</dob>
        <location>city123</location>        
    </child>
    <child>
        <age>35</age>
        <name>
            <firstname>ghi</firstname>
            <lastname>345</lastname>
            <middlename>r</middlename>
        </name>
        <education>
            <graduate>Yes</graduate>
            <masters>Yes</masters>
        </education>
        <dob>25-MAR-1985</dob>
        <location>city123</location>        
    </child>
</parent>
```

**Output XML:**

```
<parent>
    <child>
        <age>30</age>
        <name>
            <firstname>abc</firstname>
            <lastname>xyz</lastname>
            <middlename>v</middlename>
        </name>
        <education>
            <graduate>Yes</graduate>
            <masters>No</masters>
        </education>
        <dob>25-MAR-1990</dob>
        <location>city123</location>        
    </child>
    <child>
        <age>35</age>
        <name>
            <firstname>ghi</firstname>
            <lastname>345</lastname>
            <middlename>r</middlename>
        </name>
        <education>
            <graduate>Yes</graduate>
            <masters>Yes</masters>
        </education>
        <dob>25-MAR-1985</dob>
        <location>city123</location>        
    </child>
</parent>
```

I have been using XSLT 2.0 transformation file as below, but its not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/> 
    <xsl:template match= "child/education/graduate[node()]">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please don't say "huge", give us a number. A solution that works for 100Mb won't work for 100Gb.

Comment: And please don't tell us things "don't work" - tell us how they fail, Diagnosing problems always starts by looking at the symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

Either simply select the elements you know you are looking for with

```
<xsl:template match="parent">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="child[education/graduate/node()]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

or use the identity transformation template plus an empty template blocking copying of the elements you don't want:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="child[education/graduate[not(node())]]"/>
```